# SQLException even after loading JDBC driver correctly

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm new to java and I am using Visual Studio Code for making a Java project. I'm trying to write SQL queries after loading driver in Visual Studio Code, but I'm repeatedly getting SQLException. Here is my project folder:

```
src
  -com/folder
  -db
    -DBConnection.java
```

```
try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(path, username, password);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

Every time I run, I get the following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
> found for jdbc:mysql:localhost:3306/assign

I'm getting correct results when I run the same program in the `src` folder.

Comment: Which JVM version are you using ? And what build tool ?

Comment: You probably loaded a different driver to the one that your jdbc url requires.  You should get rid of the `Class.forName` call ... and check that you have the correct driver JAR for the "path" that you are trying to use.  (How do you check?  Start by reading the documentation ...)

Comment: You're using the wrong URL. It should be `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/assign` (notice the `//` before the host name).

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this type of error is missing updated jar in classpath folder.

If you are using latest version of jdbc jar make sure it correctly points to classpath where the jar is located.

Hint: put some debug statement before invoking of class so that you can be sure correct jar is invoking everytime.

Comment: thank you for the answer but there is some error in vscode java project manager. When I tried after restarting vscode I'm not getting the exception.